# AngularJS - How to use services which are defined in one module, in the controller defined in another module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am beginner to the Angular JS.
I made a service module to define only services :

```js
(function() {
 var srv = angular.module("service_module",[]);
 srv.service("HotelService", function($http, $q) {
  //My code written here
 });
})();
```

And I created module in which Controllers are written :

```js
(function() {
 var controllers = angular.module("controllers_module",["service_module"]);

 controllers.controller("searchFormController", function($rootScope, $scope) {
  //My code here
 });

})();
```

Now when I run my code, I get this error:

```
ReferenceError: HotelService is not defined
```

Please tell me where I am wrong.

Comment: did you inject 'HotelService' in your controller?

Comment: OMG! Thanks. Silly Mistake :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to inject that service inside your controller to use it.

```
controllers.controller("searchFormController", function($rootScope, $scope,HotelService ) {
    //My code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the service you have to inject it in controller.

```
var controllers = angular.module("controllers_module",["service_module"], YourServiceName);

controllers.controller("searchFormController", function($rootScope, $scope, YourServiceName) {
        //access all methods and properties of YourServiceName here
});
```